# Study the monotonicity of the following function without using differentiation and continuity.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functions, monotone-functions

Study the monotonicity of the following function without using differentiation and continuity?
$$f(x) = 3|4-x|$$
I have changed the function to the following: 
$$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
12 - 3x & { x\leq 4}, \\
3x - 12 & {x> 4}
\end{array} \right. $$

Then I want to divide my solution to 2 cases:

(a) $\forall$ $x_1,x_2$ $\in ]-\infty, 4 [$

(b) $\forall$ $x_1,x_2$ $\in ]4, \infty [$

And then in each of the two cases I will try to reach to the shape of the function in the above piecewise definition, but I have a problem in the first case because $x$ will take positive and negative values, so what shall I do?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you sketch the function? There are two cases to consider.

Comment: Besides sketching as @RideTheWavelet suggests (apply basic reflection and vertical/horizontal shift principles to $g(x) = |x|),$ you can give a piecewise definition for $f(x)$ by using the algebraic definition of absolute value, namely $|u| = u$ if $u \geq 0;$ and $|u| = -u$ if $u < 0.$ Once you have the piecewise definition in front of you, the (maximal) intervals of increase and decrease will be obvious.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro  I have done what you said but I still have a problem.

Comment: It should be clear that $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing on $(-\infty,4]$ (graph is a negative slope line there) and $f(x)$ is strictly increasing on $(4,\infty)$ (graph is a positive slope line there). The decreasing claim can be proved by the following, which I suspect you don't have to further justify: $x_1 < x_2 \leq 4$ implies $-3x_1 > -3x_2$ implies $12 - 3x_1 > 12 - 3x_2$ implies $f(x_1) > f(x_2).$ The increasing claim is similar. In fact, you can actually show that $f(x)$ is strictly increasing on $[4,\infty).$ (Examine your proof for the increasing claim when $x_1 = 4$ is allowed.)

Comment: Finally, you can also show that if $I$ is any interval that contains $4$ so that $4$ is not an endpoint of $I$ (i.e. $4$ is in the interior of $I),$ then $f(x)$ is not increasing (even non-strictly) on $I$ and $f(x)$ is not decreasing (even non-strictly) on $I.$ For "not increasing", choose $x_2 = 4$ and choose $x_1$ in $I$ so that $x_1 < 4.$ For "not decreasing", choose $x_1 = 4$ and choose $x_2$ in $I$ so that $4 < x_2.$